# How to work with trig functions when dealing with limits tending to a point, without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

> **Past Paper Question:**

For each of the following functions f , determine whether $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$
exists, and compute the limit if it exists. In each case, justify your answers.

a) $f(x)= \dfrac{2\tan^2(x)}{x^2+2x^3}$ $\text{where a = 0}$

b)$f(x)= \dfrac{\sin(\left| x \right|)}{x^2+\sin(\left| x \right|)}$ $\text{where a = 0}$

> **Attempt:**
>
> I can't use L'Hôpital's rule, but I know from my graphical calculator that the limits of a) = $6$ and b) = $1$.

Not sure how to show this, from past experience I know you have to separate the $\tan(x)$ function into $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. But apart from that I have no idea.

Comment: @mvw my university has a thing about not using L.H's rule, its not stated in the past paper that I can't use L.H's rules, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @zz20s what do you mean by using series, i.e please show below you methodology so discussions can begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to figure out if the limit exists or not, the problem is when trying to evaluate it
According to wolfram the first limit is actually 2. We can evaluate the first limit using the fundamental trig limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1 $. So 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\tan^2 x}{x^2 + 2x^3} &= \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\tan x}x{})^2 \frac{2}{1 + 2x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} 1 \cdot \frac{2}{1 + 2x}\\
&= 2
\end{align}
As for the second limit, recall the fundamental limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. An equivalent form of this limit is $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin |x|}{|x|}$. Since $x^2 = |x||x|$(as the square is positive) we  can factor
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin|x|}{x^2 + \sin|x|} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{|x|} \frac{\sin|x|}{|x| + \frac{\sin|x|}{|x|}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin|x|}{|x|}}{|x|  + \frac{\sin|x|}{|x|}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1 + |x|}\\
&= 1 
\end{align}

Comment: I do like this methodology as it's close to what my professor usually does, however the about comments have more votes. Having said that, for my purposes, and for the level of maths I am studying, I would say this is the most logical answer. I have one question though in step 2 of your methodology for the second limit, you have 2 identical sin(x) functions, but in step 3 they are equal to 2 different things, why is this?

Comment: @UniStuffz oh sorry, both the sine limits evaluate to 1. I just got lazy and wrote the 1 first in the denominator instead writing the $|x|$ first.

Answer (score 2):

Use *equivalents*:

$\tan x\sim_0 x$, $x^2+2x^3\sim_0 x^2$, hence
$$\frac{2\tan^2 x}{x^2+2x^3}\sim_0\frac{2x^2}{x^2}=2\quad\text{(not }6)$$

$\sin\lvert x\rvert\sim_0\lvert x\rvert$, one checks readily that $x^2+\sin\mkern1mu\lvert x\rvert\sim_0\lvert x\rvert$, so
$$\dfrac{\sin(\left| x \right|)}{x^2+\sin(\left| x \right|)}\sim_0\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{\lvert x \rvert}=1.$$

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing, I think I know this method by a different name, (using inequalities to reduces or increases the size of a rational), how do you know what to reduces the fractions to? For example why reduce $x^2+sin(abs(x))$ to $abs(x)$ and not $x^2$?

Comment: Implicitly, there's Taylor's expansion at order 1 (or 2, as you wish): $\sin u=u+o(u)$,  and the fact that $x^2=o(x)$ near $0$. The underlying concepts are those of asymptotic analysis, and Taylor's formula. The only caveat is equivalence of functions is not preserved by addition/substraction – only multiplication/division.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need series.

Hints:

a). $\dfrac{2\tan^2(x)}{x^2+2x^3}=2\left ( \frac{\tan^{2}x}{x^{2}} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{1+2x} \right )$

b). $\dfrac{\sin(\left| x \right|)}{x^2+\sin(\left| x \right|)}=\frac{\frac{\sin(\left| x \right|)}{\vert x\vert}}{\frac{x^2+\sin(\left| x \right|)}{\vert x\vert}}$

Comment: You don't need them, but you sure can use them! +1!